# Fixed div crashes scroll on page

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed **div** in my **HTML**, and the problem is that I can't **scroll** if that **div** is **fixed**.

Here is **jsfiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/y0kobkny/

#### HTML

```
<div class="head">
<div class="head_content"></div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
<p>yfjhgukjhkh</p>
```

#### CSS

```
.head {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72);
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    position:fixed;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to fix `.head_content` instead of `head`? https://jsfiddle.net/y0kobkny/1/

Comment: do you want all the content should fit within 10% height (ie., get scroll bar if height exceeded) or header should be fixed and only content needs scrollbar?

Comment: You never closed you 'head' div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
.head {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72);
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;//change it
    position:fixed;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    z-index:10;
    overflow-y: scroll;//add this line
}
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/u6r0xpLj/

Answer (score 0):

#### Check this <kbd>[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0kobkny/2/)</kbd>

In CSS you class name should be **`.head_content`** instead of **`.head`**,

```
.head_content {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72);
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    position:fixed;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want header part should get scroll means use like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y0kobkny/4/)**

**CSS:**

```
.head {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72);
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    position:fixed;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    z-index:10;
    overflow:auto;
}
```